# Create foreign key relationship in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, schema

This is most likely a very silly question, I am not a programmer.

I have used visual studio to create a database for my application.

The table "CapitalPlan" has primary key "ProgramID" - this needs to be the foreign key in table "MilestoneData" field "ProgramID"

Can anyone please advise how I set up the "ProgramID" in "MilestoneData" to be a foreign key?

Image shows where I'm currently at (not very far!)

Much appreciated!

image: http://i1186.photobucket.com/albums/z373/barbsbargainsltd/cDatabase_zps52ddc806.jpg

Comment: Is this for MS SQL Server?

Comment: I'm not certain.

I have created a form based c# program. On the solution explorer I created a new item - server-based database

Comment: Visual Studio prefers MS SQL Server by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under each table (Milestone Data in your case) in designer you have a 'folder' named `Keys`. If you right click it, there is a `New Foreign Key...` option. Clicking it opens a dialog for you with numerous properties of the foreign key being created. You need an ellipsis on `Tables And Columns Specification` there - it opens a new dialog, allowing to adjust source and destination tables as well as key mapping.

This way is applicable for SQL Server Management Studio, but the image you provided suggests that the solution for VS should be identical.

Comment: Thank you for getting back so quickly.

Think im in the right area, however cannot see "Keys"

http://i1186.photobucket.com/albums/z373/barbsbargainsltd/d2_zps208c2069.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I cant inspect VS2010 for this - have only 2012 on my machine. In VS2012 next to the table pane I also have a pane listing all keys and allowing to add new ones. Still, I don't know how to make it go or appear. Either way, try right-clicking the desired table and select the `New query` option. Then enter the code from @voo's answer in the query and execute it. This should do.

Comment: Thank you for your time, very helpful.

I stumbled upon a youtube vid with vs2010 relationship set up. Theres a button in the toolbar top left, not very obvious at all. Although I think I'm missing some sections described here, I will have to investigate - I assume its something to do with my settings.